# How do I read numbers from a file, sum them and print them in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How do I read numbers from a file, sum them and print them in Haskell?

I've been trying the following: I can read the numbers, but can't get them to sum.

```
square x = do
    return x


read_numbers = do
    contents <- readFile "numbers.txt"
    let linesOfFile = map (\x -> read x :: Integer) (lines $ contents)
    return linesOfFile

f = do
    map square read_numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

There is sum in Data.List and the Prelude (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum)

```
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a Source
```

> The sum function computes the sum of the numbers of a structure.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you probably don't understand the concept of [Monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) and how Haskell use them to control side-effects in programs.

Since your objective is just to sum the read numbers, you can do the following:

```
f = do
      xs <- read_numbers
      return (sum xs)
```

where `sum` has its obvious meaning and type:

```
sum :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
```

**EDIT**: Answer to Rodrigo Stv commentary.

When you check `map` type you get:

```
 map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

When you try to map your square function which has type

```
 square :: Int -> IO Int
```

you got:

```
 map square :: [Int] -> [IO Int].
```

That is a type from list of `Int` to a list of I/O operations that can return an `Int` and you cannot `sum` I/O operations. :)

As I told you, the problem here is to understand how to work with monads.

Comment: I don't. But we are both Rodrigos so thank you =). Why can't I map the square function over a IO [String] type?